# Not able to send messages to specific user based on the userID through slack's incoming webhook

Tags: java, slack-api, slack

I am able to send messages to specific user based on the channel, But i want to send messages based on userID, so i tried to get the userID of the specific user, but strangely am getting the userID of the SlackBot(slack's inbuilt bot) irrespective of the who the user is...

here is the slack doc which says we can use channelID or userID to send to particular channel: https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks

```
"channel": "U024BE7LH" ---userID
"channel": "D7Y15W6PF" ---channelID
```

In a nutshell, the problem is: am able to get the channel ID of a particular user, but the userID am getting for any user is: U3WQ78KNS (which is user ID of slack's SlackBot)

Please let me know about this strange behavior.

Comment: Your problem is sending the message or getting the user id?

Comment: getting the userID

Comment: From where are you trying to extract that information?

Comment: Basically my bot communicates by using RTM...so the bot listens from where the message is coming from and replies back to that channel

Comment: The response is a list of IM Objects. Check here: [im.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/im.list). Perhaps you are taking the first user, but u need the second one.

Comment: Thank you so much man!!!!!!!!!! that's what it was happening...

Comment: Im glad u solved your problem

Comment: Just as potentially useful context: If you send direct messages to users, without you having a bot user on the team, they will be sent to the user from @slackbot